# Como faço um filtro de pesquisa por NOME em PHP ?

Tags: php, query, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

Ja tentei de várias formas, mas tudo da problema na query...

```
Exemplo :
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post" action="home.php">
 <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="palavra" 
 placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Search"> <button class="btn btn- 
 outline- 
 danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
 </form>

  <?php 
  if(isset($_POST['palavra']) != '')
  {
    $palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
    $pesquisa = "where nome like '%palavra%' ";
  } 
  else
   {
    $pesquisa = '';
   }

    $querySelect = $link->query("select * from alunos $pesquisa");
    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($querySelect);
    echo "Foram encontrados $linhas registros";
    echo '<br>';

   ?>
```

Comment: Função `isset` retorna um booleano, então não faz sentido fazer `isset($_POST['palavra']) != ''`. Veja a [documentação](http://php.net/isset). Fora isso, recomendo que descreva qual foram os "erros na query" que você obteve.

Comment: Ah... eu sou iniciante nisso, vi num tutorial que isso deu certo para todos... mas não para mim...

os erros são :
    Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\home.php 
    on line 34

    'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null 
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\home.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown 
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\home.php on line 34'

Comment: A variável `$link`, que faz a conexão com o banco, não existe. Onde a definiu?

Comment: defini ela no conexao.php :

    <?php

    $utf8 = header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'horus');
    $link->set_charset('utf8');

    ?>

Comment: Esse arquivo não consta como incluído no seu exemplo. Poderia descrever melhor seu problema? As vezes omitir algumas partes do código tornam impossível responder a pergunta.

Comment: Ah...eu realmente não tinha incluído o link do conexao.php na minha página home.php (onde está fazendo o filtro de busca), agora que inclui... não me mostra mais erros, porém não faz a pesquisa...

Comment: `'%palavra%'` devia ser `'%{$palavra}%'`

Comment: Anderson, obrigada por estar tentando me ajudar, colocando '%{$palavra}%' deu erro : Notice: Undefined variable: palavra in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\home.php on line 36

Comment: Impossível, você definiu a variável na linha anterior. Você mudou mais alguma coisa no código?

Comment: não! kkkk não mudei nada...

Comment: Anderson, eu mosquei, perdão. Bom parece que estamos no caminho certo, fiz a alteração para '%{$palavra}%' agora e quando pesquiso o nome "daniela" realmente me retorna 1 registro, porém só mostra o texto : "Foram encontrados 1 registros" mas não aparece só o registro da daniela... continua mostrando todos os 120 alunos...

Comment: Isso é outro problema, que não foi abordado nessa pergunta. Recomendo que abra outra colocando o código relacionado à listagem.

Comment: obrigada! no momento não consigo fazer a pergunta  o site diz "atingiu o limite de perguntas" kkkk....

Answer (score 0):

Tente ajustar o seguinte

**1º - Condição do if:**

```
if(isset($_POST['palavra']) != '')
```

para:

```
if(isset($_POST['palavra']))
```

**2º - Dentro do if:**

```
$pesquisa = "where nome like '%palavra%' ";
```

para:

```
$pesquisa = "where nome like '%$palavra%' ";
```

Comment: Olá Mike... fiz as alterações e mesmo assim mostra o erro : Notice: Undefined variable: pesquisa in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\home.php on line 36

Comment: Mike, fiz umas alterações no meu código (o primeiro que postei) e mudei '%palavra%' para  '%{$palavra}%' ... está me retornando os registros agora, mas só em formato de texto , exemplo : agora e quando pesquiso o nome "daniela" realmente me retorna 1 registro, porém só mostra o texto : "Foram encontrados 1 registros" mas não aparece só o registro da daniela... continua mostrando todos os 120 alunos..

Comment: então agora é outro problema bem diferente, a query funcionou, só naõ está conseguindo exibir

Comment: teria que ver o código de como está sendo exibido isso, ou o que é feito depois de trazer os resultados

Comment: o meu home.php está assim no ínicio :

     `<?php include_once 'banco_de_dados/conexao.php' ?>
      <?php include_once 'includes/header.inc.php' ?>
<?php include_once 'includes/menu.inc.php' ?>

    #aqui começa o formulário
    <hr class="pt-5">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


       <div class="container pt-5">
    
       <div class="card card-outline-secondary">
         <div class="card-header">
          <h3 class="mb-0">Alunos - Horus Crossfit</h3> `

Comment: olha, eu acredito que você deveria testar o código pra ver se está funcionando a query, se ela está retornando os registros corretamente, se estiver eu recomendo fazer outra pergunta focada no teu problema atual, porque não tem como continuar respondendo o novo erro baseado no código do erro anterior

Comment: obrigada! no momento não consigo fazer a pergunta  o site diz "atingiu o limite de perguntas" kkkk....

Comment: kkkkkk ok, recomendo entrar em grupos do Telegram, eu participo de alguns grupos PHP, tem bastante gente iniciante lá, fazendo perguntas iguais a sua, e bastante gente ajudando

Comment: haha obrigada mike! vou verificar isso sz

Comment: de nada ;* boa sorte

Answer (score -1):

Utilize apenas: `isset($_POST['palavra'])` e tente mudar a *query* para:

```
select * from alunos .$pesquisa
```

Se não resultar descreva o erro obtido.

Comment: só usando o
      isset($_POST['palavra'])  (linha 31)  {
        $palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
        $pesquisa = "where nome like '%palavra%' ";
      } 
        else
      {
        $pesquisa = '';
      }

      deu erro : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in 
                       C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\home.php on line 31